# Is {Yt} a Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process

Suppose {B(t)} and {B˜(t)} are two independent standard Brownian motions and ρ is a constant, −1 < ρ < 1. The process Y(t) = ρB(t) + sqrt(1- ρ^2)*B˜(t) is distributed as a normal random variable at every time, Y0 = 0, and it has continuous trajectories. Is {Y(t)} a Brownian motion? (motivate your answer)

There is 5 thing we need to check:

Y0=0 ( which is given in the question)

Independent increments: Y(t1), Y(t2)-Y(t1), ...,Y(tn)-Y(t(n-1)) is independent r.v for any choice of timepoint 0

Stationary increments: Y(t+h)-Y(t) does not depend on t for any h>0

Y(t+h)-Y(t) is N(0,sigma^2*h) for all h>0

Y(t) has cont. trajectories.

I kind of want to say independent and stat increments hold but I cant realy show it.

Comment: Could the person that downvoted this question please explain how the question can be improved? The only thing I might think of is that they want to know what you have already tried out and where you encountered your problem, but to me that is not enough for giving a downvote straight on. Maybe you could already take those things I mentioned into consideration.

Comment: Almost duplicate of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/585391/

Comment: @Pedro The formatting can be improved; don't you think so? (However, I haven't downvoted this question.)

Comment: Sorry if its unclear. My first post and dont know exaclty how to write things here.